# Image click - Open a Dialog or Popup

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6

I have web page which display product images. These images are coming from server (images are not specific or dynamic images ) over HTTP request in JSON format. This JSON has information about each image.

I want to add dialog or popup box with respective image information when you click on image  with Javascript ES6 Engine. How I can pass image Information from JSON to dialog or popup when I click a specific image.

Comment: When you create the `<img>` element, put an identifier of the data in an attribute like `data-id=XXX`. Then when you click on the image, you can get the data attribute and use that to look up the data in an object, or perform an AJAX call to get it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the this. How I can access that data-id in javascript in es6 syntax?

Comment: If you write an attribute data-id="XXX", this attribute's value may be retrieved by obj.dataset.id, where `obj` is the HTML element, in your case the image.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you wrote

```
<img id="xyz" data-id="alpha" src="http://some.url/image.jpg" />
```

Then you may retrieve the `id` value writing

```
document.getElementById("xyz").dataset.id
```

In your case, since you want to use the value when the image is clicked, you may use an `onClick` event handler, like this:

```
<img data-id="alpha" src="http://some.url/image.jpg" onClick="someFunction();" />
```

and then have

```
someFunction = (ev) => {
    let id = ev.target.dataset.id;
    // Put here the code to open you dialog or popup
    // based on the data retrieved by using the id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works assuming you used the same image element mentioned by @Ed

```
<img id="xyz" data-id="alpha" src="http://some.url/image.jpg" />
```

Then drop in the following JS to select the image by the ID:

```
const image = document.querySelector("#xyz");
```

Then use the following code to "listen" for a click on the image:

```
image.addEventListener("click", popup);
```

Then use the following code to create a popup:

```
function popup() {
alert("Hello! I am a popup!!");
}
```